# WiFi stops working after some time

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have a problem with my Ubuntu.
I have **Ubuntu 14.04** as dual boot (alongside windows 10) on my **ACER E5-771G-79VT** laptop.
My network card is **Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC**.

When I start my Linux partition, the wifi works great as it should. But after some time, the pages start to load indefinitely. Meanwhile the signal icon is still full and showing that I am connected to network. After that, nothing can bring wifi back to life. The connection by cable works perfect. Also my windows partition has no problems with network.
When i restart Linux i can again use wifi for some time, until it drops again.

Now, i read some other similiar topics, but they didn't helped me, so that is why i am opening my topic.

Thank you

Comment: yes it is. I should have done better job at research. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I have a Lenovo Laptop - G50. I found that my wireless also disconnects every now and again. I installed Windows 7 and found it doing the same. The only way I could get it working in Windows was with the Specific Brand driver from the website. Even the Windows driver wouldn't make it work for longer than a few minutes, it had to be the specific driver from the website. I now use a USB wireless adapter in Ubuntu which solves the problem. Luckily I don't use wireless that often - I am usually on a cable.